# How to write multiple "and", "or" conditions in a if-statement in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, unix

I am trying to make this work. I need to check if `col_numbers` and `ok_numbers` are same, then print WORKS unless `col_numbers` or `ok_numbers` both are zero. How do I test this? I tried this but failed to get what is expected.

```
Condition1 ( I don't want to print `WORKS!` when both are zero though they both are equal):
ok_numbers=0
col_numbers=0

Condition2 (I want to print `WORKS!` because both are non-zero and equal):

ok_numbers=4
col_numbers=4
```

What am I missing in my code below?

```
  if [ ( ${col_numbers} -eq ${ok_numbers} ) -a (( ${col_numbers} -ne 0 ) -o ( ${ok_numbers} -ne 0 )) ]; then
    echo "WORKS!"
  fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use `()`s that way. In bash they create a subshell.

Instead I would do two test conditions (and also simplify logic).

```
#!/bin/bash -u

col_numbers="$1"
ok_numbers="$2"

if [ ${col_numbers} -eq ${ok_numbers} ] && [ ${col_numbers} -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "WORKS!"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

Comment: If statement doesn't close properly. May be something is missing here?

Comment: I also need to check `${ok_numbers} -ne 0` within a IF statement.

Comment: Working for me. https://ideone.com/ry9OdJ
And no you don't need to check it. The first part of `&&` has verified 2 variables are equal, so only need to check one of them (does not matter which) in the second part.

Comment: You don't need to check both `${ok_numbers}` and `${col_numbers}` because if they're equal and `${col_numbers}` is not zero, neither is `${ok_numbers}`.   The unclosed `if` statement problem suggests you didn't type something accurately.  I'd prefer to see the variables enclosed in double quotes (`"${col_numbers}"` etc) in the test condition.  The braces are optional; the quotes should be treated as necessary.  Note that if the script is invoked with non-numeric arguments, the values will be treated as zero.

Comment: Thanks. It's working. For some reason I had `!` exported as ENV.

Comment: It also can be written as ` [[ ${col_numbers} -eq ${ok_numbers} ] && [ ${col_numbers} -ne 0 ] && echo  "WORKS!" || echo "False" ]]`  in bash, for POSIX shell double brackets should be replaced to single.